# Incorrect accent after \verb

Tags: verbatim, accents

I have following snippet of code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}[0]{`\verb£Test£'}
\test

`\verb£Test£'
\end{document}
```

The second scenario works as I want: the accents around test are in the same font. However, when I nest it in the test command, the closing accent is in the same font as verbatim. Why is that? And how can I fix this?

It looks like this:

[image]

This is of course a trivial example, but I want to use accents around verbatim inside more complex commands.

Thanks,
Yves

Comment: `\newcommand{\test}[0]{\`\verb£Test£'}` is a syntax error, you can not use `\verb` in the argument of another command.

Comment: Also note that £ is only safe to use as a `\verb` delimiter if you are using a legacy 8bit encoding such as latin1, if you use UTF-8 then it will not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have `\verb` inside the argument to another command (including `\newcommand`).

The `newverbs` package provides “quoted verbatim” out of the box and also features `\newverbcommand` to do many more things.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newverbs}

\begin{document}

\qverb|test\*&}|

\end{document}
```

[image]